# Adding audio to video with FFMPEG (mixing)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I want to add an audio to a video file while keeping the original audio of the video.

I want to mix the audio of the original video with another audio file.

How can I do that with FFMPEG ?

Thanks in advance I hope I was clear

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Mix the original audio down to one track (say, left channel) in a copy of the video file [as shown](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) (substitute your audio source for FLAC if the source did not use FLAC):

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.flac -ac 1 mono.flac
```

Then, with that copy, add in the other audio as the right track. Again, substitute your audio source type for FLAC if the sources did not use FLAC.

```
ffmpeg -i left.flac -i right.flac -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]join=inputs=2:channel_layout=stereo[a]" -map "[a]" output.flac
```

More documentation may be found at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options and 
 https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html.